# Python Function Capsules

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-extensions

I found this code snippet in the help of python 2.7.5, which is a chapter about exposing a C-API to other modules in the Extending Python with C and C++ section: Providing a C API for an Extension Module

```
/* C API functions */
#define PySpam_System_NUM 0
#define PySpam_System_RETURN int
#define PySpam_System_PROTO (const char *command)
// ...
static PySpam_System_RETURN PySpam_System PySpam_System_PROTO;
// ...
static void **PySpam_API;

#define PySpam_System \
(*(PySpam_System_RETURN (*)PySpam_System_PROTO) PySpam_API[PySpam_System_NUM])
```

This snipped is for function capsules. A capsule is used to pass functions between two modules.
But what's the meaning of this snippet: `[...] (PySpam_SystemRETURN (*)PySpam_System_PROTO) [...]`.
I think it's something like a static cast. Something like `(int(*)(char s))`. But what's the meaning of this construct?

Comment: Do you mean [capsules](http://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/capsule.html)?

Comment: Sorry, yes! I have corrected this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As defined, the macro `PySpam_System` expands into:

```
(*(int (*)(const char *command)) PySpam_API[0])
```

Which is basically accessing `PySpam_API[0]`, casting it to a pointer to function receiving a `const char *` and returning `int`, and dereferencing that pointer.

It is equivalent to writing:

```
int (*)(const char *command) function_ptr = (int (*)(const char *command)) PySpam_API[0]
#define PySpam_System (*function_ptr)
```

That is, it is equivalent to declaring a variable `function_ptr` which is a pointer to the same function pointed to by `PySpam_API[0]` casted to `int (*)(const char *)`, and then using `PySpam_System` as a shortcut to dereference the pointer, which means that `PySpam_System` can be used as if it were a function, as in:

```
PySpam_System("an example");
```

This effectively calls the function pointed to by `PySpam_API[0]` with argument `"an example"`. Note that the function must be compatible with the cast.

Also, notice that the code defines a function called `PySpam_System` before defining the macro `PySpam_System`. This has the effect that if you use `PySpam_System()` before the `#define`, you will be calling this function:

```
static PySpam_System_RETURN PySpam_System PySpam_System_PROTO;
```

(Which expands to `static int PySpam_System(const char *command);`)

If you use `PySpam_System()` after the `#define`, you will be calling a macro that calls the function pointed to by `PySpam_API[0]`.